# Unable to select, copy, delete or edit text in textarea in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea where share link gets displayed. It works fine on Chrome and Mozilla, but in IE text cannot be selected (consequently it cannot be copied). You can edit it (delete and write).

I added the textarea with:

```js
exports.setTextArea = function(url) {
        $('.share .clipboard textarea').text(url);
        $('.share .clipboard textarea').height(1);
        window.setTimeout(function(){$('.share .clipboard textarea').height($('.share .clipboard textarea')[0].scrollHeight);}, 0);
      }
    
      exports.copyResult = function() {
     $('.share .clipboard textarea').focus();
     $('.share .clipboard textarea')[0].setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
        document.execCommand('copy');
      }
    
      $(function () {
        $('.share .exit-btn').on('click touchstart', shareControl.close);
        
        $('.share textarea').keydown(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
                e.target.select()
            }
        });
      });
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 230px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  -moz-user-select: all;
  -ms-user-select: all;
  user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="clipboard">
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

Can it be javascript that is causing the problems? I'm using it to generate textm set text in textarea and in the and copy it to the clipboard.

Edit: I found out that this problem remains no matter where I try to place . It's specific to IE and Edge apparently although it works when tested on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Seeing the code you posted works fine it is very likely something else is causing the issue. `Can it be javascript that is causing the problems` - Please post the relevant code. If there is any errors in the console then please post them too.

Comment: your code is working fine in IE11

Comment: which IE version that not working? what jquery version using also?

Comment: IE: 11.540.15063.0,
jquery: 3.1.1. Also there are no errors in console.

Comment: I am speculating, but I  think it is the setSelectionRage(0,**9999**) that is causing the unexpected behaviour because the value 9999 is more than the field actually contains. Experiment with smaller values, such as two, and see if it copies that value.

Comment: I've already tried without copy function itself and nothing changes. For info, the copyResult function doesn't work on IE, so I think that it's something connected to textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing this:

```
<body onload="htmlInit('XYZ');" onselectstart="if ((event.target || event.srcElement).nodeName !== 'INPUT') return false;"...>
```

to this:

```
<body onload="htmlInit('XYZ');" onselectstart="if ((event.target || event.srcElement).nodeName !== 'INPUT' && (event.target || event.srcElement).nodeName !== 'TEXTAREA') return false;"...>
```

the textarea is working as expected